# (parameter) state: unknown Object is of type 'unknown'. redux TS

Tags: typescript, redux

```
const submitted = useSelector((state) => state.post.submitted)
```

For above at state. I get error:

(parameter) state: unknown
Object is of type 'unknown'.

How is this fixed?

I have simple slice + store:

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const postSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'post',
  initialState: {
    shared: false,
    submitted: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    setShared: (state, action) => {
      state.shared = action.payload
    },
    setSubmitted: (state, action) => {
      state.submitted = action.payload
    },
  },
})

export const { setShared, setSubmitted } = postSlice.actions
export default postSlice.reducer
```

```js
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

//import slice as reducer
import postReducer from './features/postSlice'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  //combine all reducers
  post: postReducer,
})

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
})
```

I don't get this type of error on Javascript, though pops up in TS? Wat type of types need to be declared for this if needed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should follow the [TypeScript QuickStart](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#define-typed-hooks) guide and set up correctly typed hooks:

```
// store.ts

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

```
//hooks.ts

import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

Answer (score 6):

`useSelector` is a generic and can't determine what type `state` is, so defaults to `unknown`.  You need to give state a type annotation which matches the shape of `initialState`, so you'll need to break that out of the slice definition.

1. Define the interface (or use a type/type alias if you prefer)

```
interface MyState {
  shared: boolean
  submitted: boolean
}
```

2. Type cast the `initialState`, or use an intermediate typed variable (I think this is optional but a look at the documented examples suggests this is possible):

```
  // ...
  initialState: {
    shared: false,
    submitted: false,
  } as MyState,
  // ...
```

3. Add a type annotation to the callback

```
const submitted = useSelector((state: MyState) => state.post.submitted)
```

Answer (score -1):

const generalUserInfo = useSelector((state: any) => state.generalStore);

DO THIS :
state **: any**

Comment: DON'T DO THIS. Using any type is sweeping the problem under the carpet.